# Partial fractions: decompose $\frac{3x}{(x+2)(x-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading a textbook on how to decompose partial fractions. Currently, I'm unable to follow example 1, decompose $\frac{3x}{(x+2)(x-1)}$ on [this](https://openstax.org/books/college-algebra/pages/7-4-partial-fractions) page.

Screenshot:
[image]

I can follow this all the way down to "Set up a system of equations associating corresponding coefficients." at the bottom. I don't see how this was done?

i.e. How can I go from:

$$3X=(A+B)X-A+2B$$ to this:

$$3=A+B$$
$$0=-A+2B$$

Comment: How can you go from $3x =(A+B)x - A+2B$ to $\begin{cases} 3=A+B\\0=-A+2B\end{cases}$?  Two polynomials are equal as polynomials if and only if each corresponding coefficient are equal.  Equivalently, any polynomial with a nonzero coefficient is not equal to the zero-polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "equating the coefficients".

You want to make sure that $3x=(A+B)x−A+2B$ for **all** values of $x$.

But the general rule is: for each power of $x$ that appears, make sure the coefficients of that power on one side are **always** equal to the coefficients on the other side.

You take all the coefficients of $x^0$ on each side and equate them. (That is, all the constants.) This gives, in this case, nothing on the left and $-A + 2 B$ on the right.

Then you take the coefficients of $x^1$ on each side and equate them. This gives, in this case, $3 x = (A + B) x$. You don't need the $x$ so you just take the coefficients. That is: $3 = A + B$.

You might want to start getting your head round this concept by putting $x = 0$ and seeing that $0 = -A + 2B$, which gives you a start.

Comment: I found this tricky to get my head around, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to note is that we want the equation to hold for all $x$.

Notice that if we have for all $x$

$$c_1x+c_0 = d_1x + d_0$$

Then we have

$$(c_1-d_1)x+(c_0-d_0)=0$$

If we want the equation to hold for all $x$, then we require the constant term and the coefficient of $x$ to be $0$.

Hence $c_1=d_1$ and $c_0=d_0$.